# When does the docker volume become available for CMD script?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a container that links a volume to local path. This volume is used in script that is run by Dockerfile CMD.

I noticed that often this path does not exist at the time when CMD script is executed.

Is there anything I can do to guarantee that volume binding exist at time when CMD is run?

Example (although is trivial)

docker-compose:

```
...
volumes:
  - /foo:/bar
...
```

script:

```
...
cat /bar/run.txt
...
```

Comment: have you tried: `command: /bin/bash -c "cat /bar/run.txt"`?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte will try, let me see..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volumes work on container when you run it. CMD is Dockerfile command and it's about image building time. If you want to execute some scripts on image building stage you can add it by next command:

```
ADD localScript.sh /scriptForImage.sh
```